# リンク先の検索結果を表示する方法

Tags: python, html, jquery, django

djangoでwebアプリケーションを作成しています。

```
<a href=#>sample</a>
```

というコードがあったとします。このときこのリンクがクリックされるとあるサイトの入力formでsampleと検索されてその検索結果を新しいタブで開く、という挙動をするコードを考えています。
しかしどのようなコードを書けばいいのかわからずに困っています。
どなたか教えて頂けると助かります。
jqueryなどは使っても構いません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「とあるサイトの入力form」の仕様に依存します。

★ Google検索のように、GETメソッドのフォームの場合

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=sample" target="_blank">sample</a>
```

URLにquery部を付けてリンクすれ良いでしょう。JavaScriptのコードを書く必要はありません。

★ POSTメソッドのフォームの場合

不可視のフォームを組み立てて、送信すれば良いです。

```
<form action="http://httpbin.org/post" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input type=hidden name="query" value="sample">
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.querySelector('form').submit(); return false">sample</a>
```

ただし、どちらの場合でもCSRF対策などで外部サイトからのフォーム送信は拒絶しているかもしれません。